# C compiler optimization - how it is done between modules?

Tags: c, optimization

Imagine `2` source files, called `file1.c` and `file2.c`. They are both compiled separately by the compiler, and linked at the final step. Consider optimization GCC `-Ofast`. They both have its corresponding header file and headers include each others.

file1:

```c
//#include...

int bool_check;
int main(void) {
    bool_check = 1;    
    while (bool_check) {
        do_something(); //Defined in another file
    }
}
```

file2:

```c
void do_something() {
    extern int bool_check;
    bool_check = 0;
}
```

In this example, `file1` calls a function in `file2`.

- Is compiler/optimizer allowed to optimize the code in `file1` saying `bool_check` will never get changed so we don't need to perform constant read-from-memory operation?
- If no, how does it know that function in `file2` modifies the variable, if files are compiled separately?
- If yes, isn't this a compiler bug?

It is not the great real-life use case, but good for demonstration.

Comment: Look up link time optimization in relation to compiler design.

Comment: The *compiler* only deals in single [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (TL;DR: Basically a single source file with all its included header files). The compiler itself doesn't now anything else, and can't do optimizations across translation units. But as mentioned above, the *linker* can.

Comment: Optimizations are not generally discussed specifically in language specifications. They specify the behavior of the programs; how the compiler accomplishes this is an implementation detail.

Comment: But because we know that files can be linked together arbitrarily, the compiler can't make any assumptions about global variables that are exported. If you declare the variable `static` then it won't be visible to other modules, and the compiler can optimize it away.

Comment: The compiler has to assume that any function from a different translation unit could modify any global variable. However, some compilers (e.g. `gcc`) allow you to state that a function has the `const` attribute, or the `pure` attribute, which means they do not modify global state. This can allow better optimisation in some cases, without resorting to link-time optimisation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried this code: https://godbolt.org/z/fn7oY6zo9 It calls random function `do_test` which returns int but it is not defined in translation unit. Generated instructions seem to still optimize a read in `for (mytype_t* e = list_starts; e != NULL; e = e->next) {` which is only done once at the very start of program. It simply ignores the call to `do_test` which may modify the data. There is a `L3: b L3` which is essentially a never ending loop, if loading fails. If I declare variable as `mytype_t* volatile list_starts;` or `mytype_t* _Atomic list_starts;` then it looks fine.

Comment: @unalignedmemoryaccess If the list is empty, then `do_test()` is not called, so nothing can modify the global state. Hence the infinite loop. You'd need `list_starts` to be `volatile`, as you observed.

Comment: Nitpick: Those are "translation units". "Modules" is something else (a novel C++ feature).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is compiler/optimizer allowed to optimize the code in file1 saying `bool_check` will never get changed so we don't need to perform constant read-from-memory operation?

No.  It can only make that optimization if it can prove that `bool_check` actually isn't modified by the call to `do_something()`, which is only possible if it can see the code.

> If no, how does it know that function in file2 modifies the variable, if files are compiled separately?

Normally, it doesn't know.  So it has to assume that `do_something()` might modify `bool_check`, which means that it has to reload it from memory after every call.

In general, if the compiler can't see the code for a called function, it must assume that function might read or write *every* global variable in the program, as well as every static, local or dynamic object whose address has "escaped" and could possibly be known to the called function.  So all preceding writes to such objects must be stored to memory before the call, and all subsequent reads must be loaded after the call.

For example:

```
void other1(int *p);
void other2(void);

int foo() {
    int x, y, z;
    int *p = &z;
    other1(&x);
    x = 3;
    y = 5;
    *p = 7;
    other2();
    return x + y;
}
```

After the call to `other2()`, the compiler has to reload `x` from memory.  It is possible that the call to `other1()` stashed the pointer to `x` in some shared object that `other2()` can also access, in which case `other2()` might have modified `x` through that pointer.  Likewise, the `x=3` has to actually store the value `3` into memory and can't be optimized away.

On the other hand, `y=5` needn't store to memory, and `y` need not be reloaded after `other2()`; the address of `y` has never been taken and so no other code could "know" where it's located in order to modify it.  In fact, `y` need not occupy memory at all; it can simply be replaced by an immediate constant in the `return` expression.

The same is true for `z`; even though its address has been taken, it has not been passed outside the function `foo` and so it has not "escaped". This logic is called [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis). So the compiler can optimize it away without changing the program's observable behavior.

Having said all this, modern toolchains are capable of *link time optimization*, in which the compiler emits not only assembly code for each source file (translation unit) but also some intermediate representation (IR) that describes the code's semantics in more detail.  All of this information is then available to the linker, which can re-run optimization and code generation, now with the entire program "visible" at once.  At this point, the optimizer can see that `bool_check` is modified by the call to `do_something()`, though that doesn't really change anything because the compiler had already assumed that it was.  What's more relevant is that the optimizer can see which variables are *not* modified, and optimize away any dead stores or unnecessary reloads.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - seems logical. I did a test at godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/hTWffjE3f here you can see that we enter in a while loop and that for-loop is only executed once. In the translation unit, function is only declared, but not defined. Does it mean godbolt test compiler performed *link time optimization*? Technically, `do_test` could be implemented in another translation unit and could modify global variable `list_starts`, no?

Comment: @unalignedmemoryaccess: The comment from pmacfarlane above already explained that.  Look more closely at what the code does.  If `list_starts` is ever null upon starting the `for` loop`, then the `fot` loop terminates without calling `do_test` again.  The `while` loop repeats, and `list_starts` is still null because no code has executed that could change it.  So in that case we genuinely have an infinite loop. And that's what the assembly does: at `.L9` we load `list_starts` and if it's zero we jump straight to the infinite loop at `.L2`.

Comment: But if we enter the `for` loop with `list_starts` not null, then it will actually run (label `.L11` onward).  When it finishes and the `while` loop repeats, we go back to `.L9` which does in fact reload `list_starts` from memory.  As it must, since as you say, `do_test` could have modified it.

Comment: @unalignedmemoryaccess: So no, there is no LTO being done here (unless you check "compile to binary", godbolt doesn't even do linking).  If it did try to link this program it would simply fail because of the undefined reference to `do_test`.

Comment: OK - you are right @Nate Eldredge. Thanks

Comment: @unalignedmemoryaccess: By the way, since you included `stdatomic.h` and named your function `thread2`, you may also be thinking about the possibility of concurrent access?  The compiler is *not* required to reload non-atomic variables to get the result of a concurrent modification from another thread.  Because if there were such a modification, it would be a data race, which makes the program's behavior undefined.  So the compiler is allowed to assume there are no concurrent writes.

Comment: this is exactly true what you ahve said - I use mutexes before I read/write the value. I just want to ensure that compiler generates code which will ALWAYS load value from memory and must assume that it can be changed somewhere else. So `volatile` can be useful here, or at least `_Atomic`. We should separate 2 concerns - one is to ensure that only one thread/interrupt can read/write at a time and second is to ensure that compiler will always load the value from memory and not generate instructions to cache value in one of registers. I'm interested in second case now.